# Missing TextField

Tags: reactjs, uitextfield

OK, so I have another issue which is driving me bonkers.

This works (ie I see a TextField on the glass):

```
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

function MyInput() {
  
  return (
    <span>
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="input"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
          value="abcd"
        />
    </span>
  )
}
   
export default MyInput;
```

This doesn't (ie no TextField is displayed: the DOM contains <div class="MuiFormControl....." which in turn contains the  elements, but nothing in between them).)

```
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

function MyInput() {

  const myfn = () => {
    return
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="input"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
          value="abcd"
        />
  }

  return (
    <span>
      {myfn()}
    </span>
  )
}

export default MyInput;
```

Any ideas as to why the second implementation doesn't display a text input field will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rendering your component using JSX, the name of that component has to begin with a capital letter otherwise React will throw an error as unrecognized tag. This convention is because only HTML elements and SVG tags can begin with a lowercase letter.

Like this:

```
function MyInput() {
  const MyFn = () => {
    return (
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="input"
        type="text"
        fullWidth
        variant="standard"
        value="abcd"
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <span>
      <MyFn />
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, not only for fixing the problem, but also for explaining why it was failing!

Answer (score 1):

*The return statement in 'myfn' has a line break right after the 'return' keyword and because of the line break, the function returns undefined and the JSX code for the 'TextField' is never reached.*

**You should either remove the line break or use parentheses to wrap the JSX:**

```
  const myfn = () => {
  return <TextField
    autoFocus
    margin="dense"
    id="input"
    type="text"
    fullWidth
    variant="standard"
    value="abcd"
  />
}
```

**Wrap JSX in parentheses like this:-**

```
const myfn = () => {
  return (
    <TextField
      autoFocus
      margin="dense"
      id="input"
      type="text"
      fullWidth
      variant="standard"
      value="abcd"
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: As above - thanks not jut for the fix, but for explaining why it was failing.